# Is it possible to mock our own service?

Tags: symfony, mocking, phpunit

I want to mock a service that is required in a class constructor. I have an exception of PHPUnit : MyService is required, Mock_MyService_0afc7fc1 given.

But with the Request, EntityManager or other Symfony 2 component, I haven't this issue.

Here is my Class's construct :

```
use Acme\Bundle\Service\MyService;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

...

public function __construct(MyService $service, Request $request)
{
```

and my mock :

```
...

$service = $this->getMock('MyService');

$class = new Class($service, $request);
```

It's impossible to mock our own service ? Only Symfony 2 component ?

PS : If I delete `MyService`like that : `public function __construct($service, Request $request)`, this works. But I want to define my variable with it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that PHPUnit at the time of the test execution can't find (or autoload) your `MyService` class.

That means that you'll probably run into the same issues with other Mocking libraries as all of them require the original class to exist to scan it and create the mock.

It happens because you need to tell PHPUnit the Fully-Qualified Class Name.

Change your code to `$this->getMock("\Acme\Bundle\Service\MyService");` and it should work out.

(Still, give mockery a try. It's a nice library)

Comment: If you have autoloading setup, it works without the full path, though!

Comment: @markus-tharkun It works as "it mockes something" but it isn't able to give you the right methods and extend for the same class. PHPUnit isn't aware of the namespace the class was defined and it doesn't resolve any use statements in the test class (as this would require static code analysis). With https://wiki.php.net/rfc/class_name_scalars this will look a lot nice: `MyService::class` instead of the long path. But for now I'm not aware of alternatives :) (Correct me If I'm wrong and missed something)